# gtsummary footnote marks as subscript instead of superscript

Tags: r, gtsummary, footnotes

The footnotes in `gtsummary` are indexed as superscript:

[tbl_summary example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAxi2.png)

But to my knowledge, the convention in almost every research field is to use subscript. This has been -- quite understandably-- a point of confusion when presenting my tables to lay audiences. They ask me "why is your p-value squared?"

This is reproducible if you run `%>% tbl_summary() %>% add_p()` on any dataframe. The footnotes will be indexed as superscripts instead of subscripts.

There does not seem to be any way to change it using `modify_footnote`.

Is there any possible way to move it? I would like my footnote indices to look like this:

[footnotes at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq1jW.png)

without having to tweak them manually after rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gt::opt_footnote_marks()` function to change the default footnote mark. See example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

tbl <- trial %>% 
  select(trt, age, response) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p() %>%
  separate_p_footnotes() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::opt_footnote_marks(marks = "letters")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! A letter is significantly less confusing than a number in this context. Making it a subscript would still be even better; hopefully that's possible some day but this is very helpful in the interim.

Comment: Thanks! A letter is significantly less confusing than a number in this context. Making it a subscript would still be even better; hopefully that's possible some day but this is very helpful in the interim.

Comment: It may be possible to specify custom footnote markers. But it's not something I've ever looked in to.