# How to change gtsummary theme's footnote marks as subscript instead of superscript

Tags: gtsummary, flextable, gt

Under "[Writing Themes](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/themes.html#writing-themes)" in gtsummary vignette there is an option to change default expression of `as_gt` and `as_flex_table`

I need to change table's [footnote marks as subscript instead of superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956929/gtsummary-footnote-marks-as-subscript-instead-of-superscript) in my new custom theme

Following the `stackoverflow` example, I can do the following:

```
glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial) %>% 
  tbl_regression( exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
   modify_table_styling(
    columns = everything(),
    rows = !is.na(variable),
    missing_symbol = "NA"
  ) %>% as_gt() %>%
  gt::opt_footnote_marks(marks = "letters")
```

However, I don't know how to implement this in a theme for both `as_gt` and `as_flex_table`. I tried the following for `as_gt`:

```
my_theme <-
  list(
 "as_gt-lst:addl_cmds" = list(
          tab_spanner = list(
            rlang::expr(gt::opt_footnote_marks(marks = "letters"))
          )
```

I don't see any changes ?!